# Show the popup only once in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have one sample app.  The application contain popup view when i login the screen going to home page view load popup appear perfectly my problem is the popup show only once at homepage again comes to the homepage popup does not needed? How Can do this.  Any one give the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store some BOOL value in your userdefaults.
Check the value of that variable before showing the popup.

```
 if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"popDisplayed"] == FALSE)
 {
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"popDisplayed"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
      //Alert code will go here...
 }
```

Put above code before you are trying to display the alert.

So, it will display the alert only once. It will not display it agin even you restart your application.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `pop up` displaying code in `viewDidLoad`. Then it will appear only at once. I think you are written the code to show pop up in `viewWillAppear`. It will be called whenever you navigate to that `home page`. The `viewDidLoad` will be called only at once.

Answer (score 0):

Quick **Swift 3** Version:

```
if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "wasAlreadyShown") {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "wasAlreadyShown")     

    // Show your Dialog...

}
```